# Anonymity while "attacking" a target

Tags: network, penetration-test, anonymity

I'm very interested to the security topic, but sometimes I fail in understanding how a hacker would be successful like for example a group that recently claimed [they got data from FBI](http://www.wired.com/2016/02/hack-brief-fbi-and-dhs-are-targets-in-employee-info-hack/).

I wonder while they engage in such a hacking the target's logs will be telling everything you are doing, specially engaging against the government which is very rich in resources to trace and go against anyone who would attack and get data from their servers... My biggest doubt is regarding the networking perspective.

How the anonymity is done right. It is probably the hardest thing to do I guess, you would have to bypass firewalls, IDS, and a bunch of other security measures without letting a track of your location...

I know about IP spoofing, Tor, VPNs, passive attacks and Zombie machines, but is there other way to be invisible in such a good way or is it a well done combination of the options I mentioned?

How would someone be able to get maximum "invisibility" in the networking context? Sorry for my noobness :-/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remain 100% anonymous on the internet?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29196/how-to-remain-100-anonymous-on-the-internet)

Comment: In addition to the question I linked above, there are many, many questions on Security SE dealing with being anonymous. These questions are good for getting a small set of working knowledge on a subject, then asking a question to fill any gaps those questions may have :)

Comment: They can use a botnet. Yes IP addresses can be traced, but they won't usually lead to the hacker, but rather hundreds, or thousands of random compromised computers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is very complicated. You can have all sorts of recipes for hiding your IP but everything depends on the willingness and capacity of your target to go after you.

The [story of the fall of Silk Road's owner](http://motherboard.vice.com/blog/everything-the-silk-road-founder-did-to-get-caught) (Ross William Ulbricht) is a prime example of things which can go wrong when trying to hide.

The "capacity" part is a key point: local authorities for the attack target must have the legal possibility to go after a criminal. The James Bond (or any other well known case you can think of) version is that they can send hords of spies to get you but it is not likely to happen. If the attack comes from a not-so-friendly country then the forensics analysis will provide an information and then hit a wall (the entrance to that country).

Comment: Ah, I thought so, and sometimes this is probably the dead end for the authorities... I guess up to this moment is a matter of luck if the other country will cooperate or not. Thanks for help @WoJ