# Risk when having public IP

Tags: ip

I need to access CCTV system in the office environment. So I ask network people to do necessary steps. They told me that they need my public IP.   I need to know if giving my public IP is a security risk or not. If there is a risk, how to avoid the risk?

Comment: They need your public IP?  Or the public IP of the office?

Comment: public IP of the office

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29094/110133

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to access to your CCTV system from your office, you have to configure it with a public IP address (available from any part of the world), and about security risks, it depends, if your camera is password protected the risk is lower, otherwise anyone with the public IP address can see the same images that you see, and your CCTV is could to end up like the ones in this Google dork: intitle:"Live View / – AXIS". If you expose some resource on the Internet, there will always be a risk.